# Multiple lines with data labels (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I would like to plot multiple lines **with data labels** but all my attempts have returned an error message so far.

```
ggplot(data, aes(year)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = var1), color = "#E20335", size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = var1), color = "#E20335", size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = var2), color = "#292753", size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = var2), color = "#292753", size = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2010:2020) +
  scale_y_comma() +
        labs(title = 'something',
         subtitle = 'something',
         x = 'This axis title intentionally left blank',
         y = 'This axis title intentionally left blank',
         caption = 'something')
```

I want to insert the labels into this code, so that they are placed around data points. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with `geom_label()`? https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment you can try with `geom_label`. However, it is better if you provide an example dataset such as an in-built dataset or the output of `dput(data)`. Also, include the `library` you are working with to help people help you. Since you do not specify which variable do you want to label I post an example with the `mtcars` dataset

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = disp), color = "#E20335", size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = disp), color = "#E20335", size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = hp), color = "#292753", size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = hp), color = "#292753", size = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2010:2020) +
  scale_y_comma() +
  labs(title = 'something',
       subtitle = 'something',
       x = 'This axis title intentionally left blank',
       y = 'This axis title intentionally left blank',
       caption = 'something')+
  geom_label(aes(y=disp,label=carb))+
  geom_label(aes(y=hp,label=carb))
```

For this kind of plot and data it is typically better to reshape the dataset to a long format so it is easier to manage legend, color and other ggplot options[image]

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, I'm a beginner. Your suggestion works great, thank you very much. I tried `geom_text()` earlier because it seemed easier to position.